# MVC 4 Web API OData Strange Results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I previously had my Web API controller working correctly with the following code:

```
    [Queryable(ResultLimit = 30)]
    public IQueryable<Lead> Get()
    {
        return _db.Leads;
    }
```

I then added a foreign Key on my Leads table. I was getting the JSON loop error. So I decided to select only the fields I need to be returned from the controller. The following is an example of the code:

```
    [Queryable(ResultLimit = 30)]
    public IQueryable<dynamic> Get()
    {
        return _db.Leads.Select(x => new
                                    {
                                        x.FirstName,
                                        x.LeadTypeID,
                                        x.DateSent
                                    }).AsQueryable();
    }
```

When I call the api through my application or terminal, the results or returned correctly. However when I paste the url in the browser (Chrome), I get a server 500 error. Guessing an XML as opposed to JSON error. It worked before adding the relationship. I would like to solve the previous issue, but it is not critical. The area of concern is that the data is returned, but my OData filters are being ignored.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in XML serializer doesn't support anonymous types, which is why you're getting a runtime exception.  There are 3 ways you can potentially solve this:

1. Create a custom POCO to return instead of your anonymous type.
2. You can remove the XML serializer and just have your application always return JSON.  You can disable the serializer by adding: 
   `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();` to your Application_Start() method of your global.asax.cs file.
3. You can choose a different XML Serializer that supports anonymous types.  I don't know of any off hand, but I'm sure there's a few out there.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. Makes sense. Any idea why my OData filters are being ignored. Taking a look at the sql being generated and can confirm the filters are being ignored.

Comment: You might want to try making a strongly typed POCO real quick instead of using the anonymous type.  I'm not sure that the Queryable attribute supports dynamics and anonymous types.

Comment: I actually had to start a completely new project. I think I was working with a Web Api beta dll's.